# È preferibile usare il che o il gerundio in queste due frasi?

Tags: word-usage

"Cosa fai che te ne vai/andandotene via, se poi non riesci ad arrivare in tempo alla stazione?"

"Cosa concludi che te ne vai/andandotene via, se poi  non riesci ad arrivare in tempo alla stazione?"

Mi suona più naturale il gerundio, anche perché  la congiunzione "che" in questo caso non so cosa rappresenti, ma magari è solo un uso idiomatico imposto da un linguaggio quotidiano che fa uno strappo alla regola, come ad esempio:

" cosa hai che sei così nervoso?"

Anche in questo caso non capisco il senso di mettere il che là in mezzo, ma vedo che nella lingua parlata si usa comunemente.

Potreste darmi una dritta a riguardo? Grazie mille in anticipo

Comment: Manca qualcosa nella frase “anche perché la congiunzione "che" in questo caso cosa rappresenti”? E “nevoso” sta per “nervoso”?

Comment: @DaG: grazie per avermi avvisato della svista.

Answer (score 1):

Assolutamente più corretto il gerundio. La forma orale della lingua è in continuo mutamento ed anche la cacofonia può pian piano diventare una realtà di fatto bene accetta... però stando al caso da te fatto presente, la forma più corretta, in un contesto non colloquiale, è sicuramente quella al gerundio!

Comment: Benvenuto su ItalianSE! Potresti completare la tua risposta aggiungendo anche il motivo della tua asserzione, magari supportato da qualche fonte attendibile?

Comment: “però all”...? Puoi completare?

Comment: @DaG: perdonami... è stata la prima risposta che io abbia mai inserito. Per un errore avevo scritto la restante metà frase in un altro pannello.

Answer (score 0):

Come ha già detto Adriano, il gerundio suona decisamente meglio.
In un contesto informale, se vuoi, puoi evitare l'uso del gerundio dicendo:

"Ma cosa te ne vai **a fare**, che/se poi non riesci ad arrivare in tempo alla stazione?"
"Ma cosa te ne vai **a fare**, che/se **tanto** poi non riesci **nemmeno** ad arrivare in tempo alla stazione?"

Nota che queste domande retoriche andrebbero pronunciate con un tono d'ammonimento piuttosto che di curiosità.

Comment: Preferisco "che non riesci ad arrivare in tempo alla stazione", magari in una frase come "Ma dove vai, che non riesci ad arrivare in tempo alla stazione?" alla quale presumo segua "Ti porto io."

Comment: O magari "Resta qui con me, amore mio"